# Zend: Where can i place custom classes in zend folder structure?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to put projecct dependent custom class in zend folder structure. I googled and found that we can put it in models folder, but we use models folder for database related classes. So I am confuse. Please help where can i put it so i can access it by directory mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my way:

I create in library path, folder 'My'. 
There I put file Utils.php.

So in Utils.php I have class

```
class My_Utils { /* some functions... */ }
```

in configs/application.ini   autoload namespace 'My' with this line:

```
autoloaderNamespaces.my = "My_"
```

So in controller you can use that class like

```
$utils = new My_Utils();
$utils->someFunction();
```

---

Other way, you can autoload that folder(My) in bootstrap

```
protected function _initAutoLoad() {
// Add autoloader empty namespace
$autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
        array(
            'basePath'      => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace'     => '',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
            'model'         => array(
                    'path'      => '../library/My/',
                    'namespace' => 'My_'
                ),
            ),
        )
);
return $resourceLoader;
}
```

Comment: means creating a folder in zend library folder where all Zend lib class and folder exists?

Comment: in library folder of project: project/library/My - maybe you put in (project/library/) Zend folder with zend class, but I suggest that Zend folder put in php path, not in library folder of application

Answer (score 0):

Look up [autoloading](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) in Zend.

This will let you define your own application folder and then include the ZF library.

From this application folder you can do as you wish when it comes to folders and classes and the autoloader will load them all for you without the need for includes or requires.